# Append Query That Also Selects A Lookup Table Value Based On Text Parsing?

Tags: parsing, append

I've posted a demo Access db at http://www.derekbeck.com/Database0.accdb . I'm using Access 2007.

I am importing an excel spreadsheet, which my organization gets weekly, importing it into Access. It gets imported the table [imported Task list]. From there, an append query reformats it and appends it to my [Master Task List] table.

Previously, we have had a form, where we would manually go through the newest imports, and manually select whether our department was the primary POC for a tasking. I want to automate this.

What syntax do I require, such that the append query will parse the text from [imported Task list].[Department], searching for those divisions listed on [OurDepartments] table (those parts of our company for which we are tracking these tasks), and then select the appropriate Lookup field (connected to [OurDepartments] table) in our [Master Task List] table?

I know that's a mouth full... Put another way, I want the append query update the [Master Task List].[OurDepartments], which is a lookup, based on parsing the text of [imported Task list].[Department].

Note the tricky element: we have to parse the text for "BA" as well as "BAD", "BAC", etc. The shorter "BA" might be an interesting issue for this query.

Hoping for a Non-VBA solution.

Thanks for taking a look!

Derek

PS: Would be very helpful if anyone might be able to respond within the work week. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Append-Query-Selects-L-t1984607.html